# query in knex js for users and password validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, knex.js

I want to create a query with knex js using the data from the template (using handlebars and expressjs) to validate a user. I created a query and then added it to a variable that after validate the user to login.
The point is that I am having troubles to make the knex query to do what I want it to do, and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
    var usernameReq = req.body.username;
    var passwordReq = req.body.password;
    var pass;
    knex('users').where({
    username: usernameReq }).select('password').then(
    function(result){
        pass = result;
        }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});

if (passwordReq === pass){
  //login  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knex uses promises, that are asynchronous.

the `if (passwordReq === pass)` is outside the promise. That means the result will not be available.

Place the `if` and all code depending on the query result (such as the http response itself) inside the `then(...)`.

Note also the result is an array of objects, even when referencing a single column of a single line. So to refer to the password you must use `result[0].password`

```
var usernameReq = req.body.username;
var passwordReq = req.body.password;
knex('users')
  .where({ username: usernameReq })
  .select('password')
  .then(function(result) {
    if (!result || !result[0])  {  // not found!
      // report invalid username
      return;
    }
    var pass = result[0].password;
    if (passwordReq === pass) {
      // login
    } else {
      // failed login
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```